# Java creates three seperate log files with FileHandler, but only when run via cron

Tags: logging, java, cron

Pretty strange problem I've got.

I'm running a small java application every 10 minutes to do some database work. It logs its activity in a file. This works perfectly well except when it's run as a cron job, when it inexplicably creates 4 seperate copies of the log file. a.log, a.log0, a.log1, a.log2.

I understand it does this when there's a lock on the file, but I can't think of any reason why would this be the case, especially why it only happens with cron.

It's able to write the log information to all four files, including the correct one, so why is it creating an extra three?

I'm closing the FileHandlers at the end of the applications life, so it's not that. Setup is simply:

```
    rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");

    //remove current handlers
    for (Handler h : rootLogger.getHandlers()){
        rootLogger.removeHandler(h);
    }

    Handler infohandler    = new FileHandler ("/dir/info.log",  true);
    Handler errorhandler   = new FileHandler ("/dir/error.log", true);

    Formatter format = new CustomFormatter();
    infohandler .setFormatter(format); 
    errorhandler.setFormatter(format);

    infohandler .setLevel(Level.INFO);
    errorhandler.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

    rootLogger.addHandler(infohandler);
    rootLogger.addHandler(errorhandler);
```

With:

```
infohandler.close(); errorhandler.close();
```

I'm only calling the function once at the moment, with:

```
rootLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Log this");
```

The cron job is pretty simple:

```
*/10 * * * * root /usr/bin/java -jar /dir/db_clean.jar
```

Any ideas? This is stumping me.

Permissions are all -rw-r--r--, and owned by root.

Comment: What makes you think a java question is on topic here ?

Comment: I put it here because it's something to do with cron, perhaps it's being run 3 times, I have no idea.

Comment: Cron has been around for a few decades, it tends to work pretty predictable :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks relevent:
http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/logging/FileHandler-source.html

In the first comments, one of the last things noted describes a result of a pattern being specified which creates 3 files like you describe. Perhaps knowing why leads you to the answer of how to fix.